# How to mask corners of static content of oval-shaped div?

Tags: css

Here's the HTML:

```
<div class="root">
    <div class="oval">
        <div class="val"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and here's the relevant CSS, so far:

```
.oval {
  box-sizing: padding-box;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 10px solid black;
  border-radius: 60px;
  position: relative;
}

.oval .val {
  width: 93%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
}
```

Go [here](https://jsfiddle.net/9e4os3e8/) to see what it looks like at the moment.

I want to mask the square corners of the `.oval .val` element, so that they appear to be behind the "opening" suggested by the `.oval` element's border.

*The right edge of `.oval .val` element should run vertically from top to bottom, without any rounding.*

**NOTE:**  The width of the `.oval .val` can be anything between 0% and 100%, including problematic values such as 93%.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add

```
.oval {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

to your CSS.

To explain this, I've added a background-color to `.val` class

```css
.oval {
  box-sizing: padding-box;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 10px solid black;
  border-radius: 60px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.oval .val {
  width: 93%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
}

.val {
    background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="root">
    <div class="oval">
        <div class="val"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Add overflow: hidden; to the .oval class.